# Img wont display from dabase using razor syntax

Tags: html, image, model-view-controller, razor

I have an image stored in the database as '../Images/background.jpg'.

These images are eventually to be stored in the cloud somewhere but for development I am just storing them on the website.

in my view I have the following

```
<img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImgUrl)" alt=""/>
```

This produces the following in source which is I would expect.

```
<img src="../Images/background.jpg" alt="">
```

However this does not display the image when rendered.. I am new to MVC coming from webforms and trying to get my head around things.

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the issue by replacing ...

```
<img src="../Images/background.jpg" alt="">
```

... with ...

```
<img src="/Images/background.jpg" alt="">
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11517030)

Comment: @yarons : It did look as a complete answer to the question to me. It was just rather poorly formulated, which I just fixed!